# Как можно вывести случайный элемент из массива и потом удалит этот элемент из массива?

Tags: php

У меня есть массив:

```
$input2 = array("S1", "S2", "S3", "S4", "S5", "S6", "S7", "S8", "S9", "S10").
```

Мне надо вывести от туда случайный элемент из массива и отображать этот  элемент на экране и потом удалить этот элемент из массива.

Answer (score 1):

```
$i = rand(0, count($input2) - 1);
echo $input2[$i];
unset($input2[$i]);
```

Comment: хотел было добавить в конце `header('Location: http://php.net/docs.php');`... еле удержался -))

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, то `unset()` не сдвигает индексы. И, возможно, еще понадобится вызвать `array_merge()` чтобы индексы шли без пропусков

Comment: ну какбы в ТЗ не было сказано, что индексы нельзя прореживать :)

Comment: ну т.е, если по сути - вы правы, повторные вызовы начнут сбоить

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = ["S1", "S2", "S3", "S4", "S5", "S6", "S7", "S8", "S9", "S10"];
while($arr) {
    shuffle($arr);  //перемешивает массив
    echo array_pop($arr);  //извлекает последний элемент массива уменьшая его      
                           //можно так же использовать array_shift()
}
```